# Dwitiya Nasta: importance of second day

Tags: customs

I heard in one upanyasa a vidwan say that we should must continue the activity/work on second iteration; he said "dwitiya nasta" will not result in good outcome.
For example:

- if you start reading something today and this is supposed to be a daily routine, you must do it second day. If you dont do it, you are likely to fail in achieving the outcome.
- Similarly, if you decide to go to temple every week, you must go second week...

The message is, don't give up at first instance--you may not like it but try one more time before deciding. He was suggesting our views may change on second day.

Now to the question: is there anywhere in scriptures this second day's (iteration's) importance is quoted? Or, any references to stopping 'dwitiya nasta'.